# How to change date to nearest date in another date frame in R?

Tags: r

```
date <- as.Date("2020-12-05")

date2 <- as.Date(ymd("2020-12-07"):ymd("2020-12-30"))
```

Assuming I have the 2 above date values

How do I write code to change the value in date to its nearest counter part in date2? i.e. changing date value to 2020-12-07.

Thanks

Comment: A similar question has answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71016735/merge-two-dataframes-by-nearest-date-in-r

Answer (score 1):

Compute differences between `date` and `date2`, and index using `which.min()` of these differences.

```r
date <- as.Date("2020-12-05")
date2 <- seq(as.Date("2020-12-07"), as.Date("2020-12-30"), by = "1 day")

date2[which.min(abs(date2 - date))]
# "2020-12-07"
```

Note in case of ties (eg, both a date two days earlier and two days later exist), this will return whichever occurs first. As suggested by @I_O, you can sort `date2` to control whether the earlier or later date is returned in this case:

```r
# to return earlier date
date2_asc <- sort(date2)
date2_asc[which.min(abs(date2_asc - date))]

# to return later date
date2_desc <- sort(date2, decreasing = TRUE)
date2_desc[which.min(abs(date2_desc - date))]
```

Comment: Is there a way to return a value that exists 2 days later instead of earlier?

Comment: You  could sort the dates you want to pick from in descending order (latest date first), so the latter of two equidistant dates will occur first.